# Java: Convert .xlsx file (Microsoft Excel) with graphs and other tabular data to Rich Text HTML

Tags: java, email, excel-2010, richtext

How can I convert .xlsx file (Microsoft Excel) with graphs and other tabular data to Rich Text HTML using Java?

Answer (score 0):

For example by using apache POI library